# Low-RAM Linux Distro Specifically for serving static sites

Tags: distribution-choice, webserver

I'm looking for a near-zero-configuration linux distro that is designed specifically for serving static web sites and nothing else on a low-RAM machine (I'm planning on 128MB, but the option of less would be nice).

Any ideas of a linux distro specifically tuned for serving static sites in a small footprint?

Comment: i don't have idea on distro buf if you want to choose webserevr, lighthttp is good option..!

Comment: This question is asking for opinions. While it may or may not be a valid question to ask, it won't fit the current Q&A format of this site. Any distro can be tweaked to fit your need. You should edit it so we're able to give a black and white answer. For instance "how can I tweak Debian so it fits my specific needs?" might be, in my opinion, a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [Lightweight Linux to host VM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88374/lightweight-linux-to-host-vm) and the (non-exhaustive) list of [leightweight distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Linux_distribution). One that is missing there is [OpenWrt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWRT), which although designed primarily for SOHO routers can certainly be ran on general purpose hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Any standard distro without a running GUI should be fine. I'd use Debian, but that's just my personal preference.